# Need assistance to improve my prime number calc code python

Tags: python, primes

python beginner here, in fact a very beginner programming student. I had an assignment to write a program that determined whether a number entered was a prime or not. I pasted the code below. Was due by midnight so I already turned it in as it is but I’d still like to improve/learn for my own sake. I’m wondering how this could be taken out of the brute force way whilst still being a “while loop” A couple problems I had was I tried using the square root calculation but everything came back false. I tried doing a print “is a prime” else “not a prime” always came back jacked up. What I have below does work, but it’s not “efficient.” Anyway I appreciate any assistance.

```
def is_prime():

    inp = input("Enter your number: ")
    if not (inp.isdigit() and float(inp).is_integer() and  float(inp) > 1):
        raise ValueError("Not an integer, try again")

    val = int(inp)
    i = val - 1
    ret = True

    while(i > 1):
        if(val % i == 0):
            ret = False
        i = i -1
    return ret

print(is_prime())
```

Comment: You could start by skipping all even numbers

Comment: check out the sieve of eratosthenes algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: run until sqrt of I and return the first time you return false

Comment: @abhilb: That's good for finding all primes up to a limit, but it does a lot of work that isn't necessary if you just want to check the primality of a single number. (It's worth checking out anyway, though, even if it's the wrong tool for this particular job.)

Comment: Incidentally what you're asking for here is really *code review*, which has a dedicated [site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although there's a lot of overlap and this is a perfectly decent question on either in this case, as you do have a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is an example of code for check if is prime number with relative good aproach:

```
def isPrime(n) : 

    # Corner cases 
    if (n <= 1) : 
        return False
    if (n <= 3) : 
        return True

    # This is checked so that we can skip  
    # middle five numbers in below loop 
    if (n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0) : 
        return False

    i = 5
    while(i * i <= n) : 
        if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0) : 
            return False
        i = i + 6

    return True


# Driver Program  
if (isPrime(11)) : 
    print(" true") 
else : 
    print(" false") 

if(isPrime(15)) : 
    print(" true") 
else :  
    print(" false")
```

i suggest you see this article and check the teory of prime numbers
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-check-whether-a-number-is-prime-or-not/

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def is_prime():

    inp = input("Enter your number: ")
    if not (inp.isdigit() and float(inp).is_integer() and  float(inp) > 1):
        raise ValueError("Not an integer, try again")

    val = int(inp)
    root = int(math.sqrt(val));
    for i in range(2 , root+1 , 1):
        if(val%i==0):
            return False

    return True

print(is_prime())
```

This is an working algorithm in O(sqrt(n)) .

Comment: Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few modifications I would do. The first and most obvious one for efficiency, is that you don't have to check if every number from 1 up to your test integer to see if it's a divisor, because the highest theoretical possible divisor will only be half the size of the test integer.

That immediately shortens the loop by a factor of 2. We can set it as simply as:

```
i = val // 2
```

You also don't have to do `ret = True` only to later `return ret`, you can simply `return True` in this simple case. The same is true about `return False` which will really help us with efficiency, because once we found even one divisor we can just return `False` and be done, no need to have the function keep running calculations.

Another thing - a function called `is_prime` sounds like it should take an integer argument instead of asking for one in the function body, so maybe put the input request outside of it. (I assume this will help you once another excersize asks you to check multiple prime number ranges)

Another thing is your integer validation at the top. All those conditions are not needed, because `val = int(inp)` would throw a `ValueError` anyway, and your loop would never start if the value is below 1 (it won't start below 4 in my example, it would just `return True` immediately).

All of what I said combined:

```
def is_prime(val):
    i = val // 2
    while(i > 1):
        if(val % i == 0):
            return False
        i = i -1
    return True

inp = input("Enter your number: ")
result = is_prime(int(inp))
print(result)
```

And let's test it out:

```
>>> for i in range(40):
...     if is_prime(i):
...             print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
```

You can always add a check for the values of `0` and `1` to have them evaluate to `False`, as needed from the conditions of your excersize.

This could all be a one-line btw:

```
def is_prime(val):
    return not any(val % i == 0 for i in range(val // 2, 1, -1))
```

You can test it out yourself, the result is identical to the above example

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Much appreciated!